# Show a text field only if date of birth input is over eighteen years old

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Currently, Im using vue.js to build a project.The condition is when the passengger type is adult and Date of birth input by the user is 18 years old and above, then only show the text field.

```
    <DatePicker
       v-model="form.DOB"
       is-expanded
       update-on-input
    >
    </DatePicker>

    //column to show/hide depends on the dob input
    //show column if dob is 18 years old or else hide it
    <v-col v-if="modelValue.PaxType === 'ADT' && ageEighteen">
    <v-text-field
       placeholder="ID"
       v-model="form.ID"
    ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>

    computed: {

    ageEighteen() {
      if (moment().subtract(18, "years") === false) {
        return false; 
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    },

}
```

Comment: No, when the dob default value the text field already show.

Comment: What is the format of your datepicker, when you select a date the value of form.DOB is?

Comment: 1. The format of datepicker is import from v-calendar(vue3).                                           2. The value of form.DOB is used for get the latest date.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that of multiple way, but to stay on yours.

```js
<template>
  <DatePicker v-model="form.DOB" is-expanded update-on-input />
  <v-col v-if="userIsMajor">
    <v-text-field placeholder="ID" v-model="form.ID"></v-text-field>
  </v-col>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
   return {
     form: {
      DOB: '',
     },
   }
  },
  computed: {
    userIsMajor() {
     // moment() = the current date
     // diff calculate the difference between two date, the first argument is your date and the second the format you want
     // You don't really respond about the format, so i done it with a common format wich is YYYY-MM-DD
     return moment().diff(moment(this.form.DOB, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'years')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```